# Python remove last line of a file

Tags: python, file

I have some files like this:

```
a:...
a:...
a:...
a:...
count = ...
```

and I just need to keep the `a:...` values lines.
What is the fastest way to remove that last line (which always starts with `count =`) ?

Comment: What do you want to do with the values? Get them into some data structure, modify the file, or write them to some other stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution:

```
lines = file.readlines()
lines = lines[:-1]
```

After opening your file in python as reading mode you could do that for deleting your last line.

Comment: That is, after you open your file like `file=open('/dir/to/file/file.txt','r')` or `with open('dir/to/file/file.txt','r') as file:`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `readlines()` function and apply the slice like

```
 lines = yourfile.readlines()
lines = lines[:-1]
```

Many other methods could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877999/delete-final-line-in-file-via-python)

Comment: Thank you Avinash. I am so new to python!