# How to remove last N lines from txt file with Python?

Tags: python

I would like to know what is the fastest and more efficient way of deleting last N lines of a .txt file.

I have been looking for different previous questions and I found that reading and copying lines again is one way.

[Remove lines from textfile with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064184/remove-lines-from-textfile-with-python)

Nonetheless, I have been trying to look for other way such as skiprows or skipfooter on pandas and be able to save the outcome to other txt.

At the same time, I have seen threads about "head" and "sed" but not sure about their usage in Python.

Could you, please, give advice on this topic?

Comment: How would you know which lines are the last N lines without reading it? (If you can, you can just read the lines you need)

Comment: In here, you have pretty low level answer how to remove last line, maybe it will help you gain proper performance results with more than just one, final line :)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10289740/5407075

Comment: Thank you for your answers BlueSheepToekn and Damian!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want to skip last n lines using pandas then:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.txt', skipfooter = N)
df.to_csv('yournewfile.txt')
```

Change the delimiter using `sep = ...` if necessary

Alternatively do as per the answer you cited, but using `with open(..)` as good practice:

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as f1:
    lines = f1.readlines()

with open('yournewfile.txt', 'w') as f2:
    f2.writelines(lines[:-N])
```

Comment: First option is the one I was looking for because It is so easy to avoid the last N lines. Then just need to save the read to other file. Thanks!

Comment: this method can be very time consuming on big files. Writing the whole file again can take very long time