# Python remove the unhasable block in the YAML file

Tags: python

Below is my sample **test.yaml** file , in that i received the values for the **a** and **b** block and  i am trying to completely remove the **c** block from the file where we have the unhashable keys are present using Python.

```yaml
applications:
  a:
    chart:
      url-details: https://adbc/a-12.tgz
    images:
      repo: a:23434
  b:
    chart:
      url-details: https://adbc/b-13.tgz
    images:
      repo: b:2345

  c:
    chart:
      url-details: https://adbc/{{ c }}.tgz
    images:
      repo: :{{ c }}
```

Can someone please help me in giving me some lead on this requirement ?

Comment: Why don't you open `test.yaml` in a text editor and delete the last 5 lines?

Comment: i would like to automate this operation  using python

Comment: Use [PyYaml](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/) to work with `.yaml` files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove last N lines from txt file with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54399735/how-to-remove-last-n-lines-from-txt-file-with-python)

Comment: I am trying to completely delete the block in the YAML file where the values are not updated and still with the unhashable key

Comment: in real scenario i dont know how many lines i need to delete , currently in the sample YAML i mentioned **c** block has unhasable keys but in next run **a** block may have unhashable keys , hence i need to delete the blocks dynamically based on the unhashable keys.