# Remove last line from text file

Tags: python

I have the following code and it works fine:

```
with open(input_file, 'rb') as f:
            #may be a large file, seeking without iterating
    f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END)
    while f.read(1) != b'\n':
        f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_CUR)
    last_line = f.readline().decode()

last_record = json.loads(last_line)
```

Now, I do not want the last line and want to remove it from the original file, and then the original 2nd last line becomes the last line & assign to `last_record`. How should I modify above code to make it happen?

The `input_file` can be very big and there can be millions of rows. I do not want to create any temporary variable just for removing the last line.

Comment: @DavidS No, I do not want to store the all lines into something, as the file can be very big, a few gigabytes with millions of rows.

Comment: refer to this specific answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10289740/8890604

Comment: Generally when doing research on SO you should look through more than just the accepted answer; the OP's constraints may be different to yours.

Comment: @DavidS Thanks for this. Unfortunately this specific answer did not work. The last line was not removed at all. No error was observed though.