# python file how to delete the last line

Tags: python, list, operating-system, readfile, writefile

I have a file that contains:

```
Line_1
Line_2
Line_3
Line_4
```

I want to delete the last line of the file `Line_4` while opening the file, NOT using python list methods, and as follwoing:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    if len(lines) > 3:
        f.seek(0)
        for i in lines:
            if i != 4:
                f.write(i)
        f.truncate()
```

The above solution is not working. I also have used the `os.SEEK_END` as follwoing:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    if len(lines) > 3:
        f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        f.truncate()
```

But, it is not working as well !

Comment: `f.readlines()` reads all lines, so your `f.seek()` is useless.

Comment: So, How would you find the `len` of the lines, to which you truncate ?

Comment: did you try this already? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10289740/16841774

Comment: In the first option, i is a line iterator being compared against an integer. It should've been something like *for in range(len(lines)-1)* and then *if i<=3: f.write(lines[i])*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you want to delete Last line from file using `.truncate()` you can just save previous position before retrieving next line and call `.truncate()` with this position after you reach end of file:

```py
with open("file.txt", "r+") as f:
    current_position = previous_position = f.tell()
    while f.readline():
        previous_position = current_position
        current_position = f.tell()
    f.truncate(previous_position)
```

If you need just need to remove all lines after certain index you can just retrieve new line this amount of times and call `.truncate()` on current position:

```py
index = 4
with open("file.txt", "r+") as f:
    for _ in range(index - 1):
        if not f.readline():
            break
    f.truncate(f.tell())
```

Or shorter:

```py
lines_to_keep = 3
with open("file.txt", "r+") as f:
    while lines_to_keep and f.readline():
        lines_to_keep -= 1
    f.truncate(f.tell())
```

Comment: Pretty good answer, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, using `read().splitlines()`

```
file_name = "file.txt"
data = open(file_name).read().splitlines()
with open(file_name, "w") as fh:
    for idx, line in enumerate(data):
        if idx >= 3:
            break
        fh.write(f"{line}\n")
```

and if you would like to only remove the last line you can instead type: `if idx >= len(data) - 1:`

Comment: there's `r+` modificator, take a look

Answer (score 0):

The most effiecient way to get rid of last line will be using subproccess module with 'head' command to get rid of the last line:

Input:

```
Line_1
Line_2
Line_3
Line_4
```

Code:

```
import subprocess

filename = 'file.txt'

line = subprocess.check_output(['head', '-n', '-1', filename])

line = line.decode('utf-8')

print(line)
```

Output:

```
Line_1
Line_2
Line_3
```