# Iteratively drop final row of text from files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, drop

I have lists of files in folders where I want to delete the last entry; I have each of these saved as a .txt file.  The lists will differ in length, so I can't say, for example, always delete the 7th member from the list.  These have random names, so I just want to import a list of files (or a folder) into python and delete the last member.

I've found this bit of code: [Delete Lines From a File in Python](https://pynative.com/python-delete-lines-from-file/) that works well for an individual file.  This reads a .txt, deletes one line, and resaves as a .txt.  For my purposes, this will work, because then I can input all of my updated .txt files into a merged dataframe.

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r+') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    fp.seek(0)
    fp.truncate()
    fp.writelines(lines[:-1])
```

However, I'm looking for a way to import all of my files without typing in their individual names.  I've used `glob` for this before eg:

```
interesting_files = glob.glob('/Users/location/*.txt')
dataframe1 = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, sep= ' ', names =['folder','num_files'])
                            for f in interesting_files))
```

So, how can I import many files instead of just `file1.txt`—either one source location with all my files in there like glob does, or as a for loop?  Are there other approaches that would work, like reading in each .txt file into a dataframe, then dropping the final row before reading in the next .txt file?

Comment: That's weird method, why not just call [`.truncate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.truncate) with return of current position *(using [`.tell()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.tell))*? Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70565132/10824407) under [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70564882/10824407).

Comment: I saw your .tell() post as I was researching this.  However, that only appears to work for a single file, not iteratively working through many files.

Comment: Well, put it inside a loop which iterate over files and proceed

Answer (score 0):

The [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) method supports a `skipfooter` parameter. So you can use that while reading it. No need for preprocessing.

To read all files in a folder, I'd do a list comprehension.

`[pd.read_csv(file, skipfooter = 1) for file in interesting_files]` will return a list of DataFrames. This can then be wrapped by a `pd.concat`:

`df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, skipfooter = 1) for file in interesting_files])`