# Large CSV file with millions of rows, need to remove last row

Tags: csv, large-data, large-files

I have a large csv file with about 15 million rows. How do i remove the very last row of the file using chunks?

Or, do i have to read the file, can i go directly to it and remove the row?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove the last line from a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881930/remove-the-last-line-from-a-file-in-bash)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877999/delete-final-line-in-file-with-python